# jQuery Ajax success response returns HTML and not my intended value

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm calling the Page Method and it's returning all of the HTML in this page and not the value of 1 or 0.
I don't know why this is. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{}',
    url: "main.aspx/IsInfoComplete",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(data.d);
            // act on return value:
            if(data==0) {
              // todo - 
            } else if (data==1) {
              // todo - 
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Server:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]

public int IsInfoComplete()
{
    int returnValue = 0;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "GetIsUserInfoComplete";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        returnValue = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception) { /* todo - */ }
}
return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: why are you logging `data.d` but using `data` in the if statement? One of those is wrong because an int shouldn't have a .d property or if it's an object with .d being the int then you should check that in your if.

Comment: Did you check what the actual request returns ?

Comment: i was checking if anything was in data.d ;  aside from that, data contains the entire page response and i am trying to figure out how to return the 1 or 0 to the data argument.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `.aspx` and not `.asmx`?  As Gaby said, what happens if you create a pure HTML form that calls this?

Comment: yes, i want an .aspx with the WebMethod().  Should it matter if the form is pure html?  The ajax call is targeting a specific method and should handle the return value of that method, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might try is to write your `success` function like this,

```js
success: function (result) {
                if (result!="False") {
                    //it worked
                }
                else {
                   //it failed                 
                }
            },
```

And change your server side method to return a `bool`. This would probably get you the desired results. I had to do this in something I wrote and it worked just fine. Little silly that you have to check for "False" but it worked.

**Note:** Case matters when looking for the word "False"

Comment: Tried this, and result contains absolutely no value - it's empty.

Comment: 3 things, what version of asp are you using? Have you put a break point in the server side function to see what it's returning? Also what version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: .net 3.5 and it returns either 1 or 0 (which i now convert to true or false based on your suggestion).  i'm using 1.7.1 from google's cdn.

Comment: hm that's what I was using. If you are using IE as a browser you can put break points in you're JQuery code. From there see what the `result` or `data` object looks like. Chances are your data is being wrapper and just needs to be access through a property.

Comment: the value of data is always  'undefined'.

Comment: I started a new project just to test this and it works just fine.  data.d returns either 'true' or 'false'.  So not really sure what's going on in this original project.

Comment: Good to hear. Not sure whats going on but Visual Studios does have a interesting way of "HELPING" you with some background stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Look's like this is messing it up.. **data** here is an object and you are trying to compare the data with a 0 or a 1

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              console.log(data); // Check the format of data in object
            if(data != null){
               console.log(data.d); // Generally your actual dat is in here
              // act on return value:
              if(data.d ==0) {
               // todo - 
              } else if (data.d ==1) {
                // todo - 
            }
        }
    },
```

If thats the case is your WebService returning a json object in the first place..
You need to decorate your webservice with this..

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]

public int IsInfoComplete()
{
```

And set the `dataType :'json'` in your ajax request

Comment: What is data .. If not can you post the json object you get in the browser

Comment: it's not returning a json object;  it will return either True or False.

Comment: k.. Then check the browser and see the response you see in the console section